# Sources to Teach .net Developing

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, .net

My IT Director asked that I get together (For Next Week!!!!) a lesson plan to teach him and our other developer .Net programming pretty much from the ground up in 6 two hour courses. Up until I was hired 5 years ago, all of our software solutions were in an older technology, namely VBA in MS Access, and the plan is to convert to .Net Web Applications. They are very intelligent, just have not had the time to dive into .Net.

So I'm asking for advice or ideas on how to structure these 6 courses and any sources you think I can turn to. I need to fit in Css Styling, C#, Jquery/Javascript/Ajax, Browser Debugging, Unit tests, etc...

Thank you!!!

Comment: 12 hours to learn that many concepts, wow, they have to be really very intelligent :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't already familiar with it, I recommend checking out [www.pluralsight.com](http://www.pluralsight.com)

Comment: Apparently this question will be delete soon, but thank you! This helps!

Comment: Questions asking for off site resources are off topic for Stack Overflow.  Don't encourage them by answering them.